# How do I make a UIButton appear at a scheduled time interval?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

So I have a timed delay action so that one when one presses the button it would show a label after the set figure of time (5seconds)

```
-(IBAction)start{

Desc.text = @"Text appears";
[self performSelector:@selector(delay) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

}

-(void)delay{

Desc2.text = @"Text to appear in 5 seconds";
[self performSelector:@selector(delayA) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

}
```

As for the next line of code I'm trying to make is that instead of a label will come up after a scheduled time interval I'm trying to get a Button to appear in 5 seconds.

Can anyone help?

Comment: you want to first button is hide and then after 5 second button will be shown,right??

Comment: use `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:]`

Comment: what do you want exactly ? I have same question as @ParasJoshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your UIButton is must Hidden for example your button name is btn1 then in `viewDidLoad:` Method Write this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    btn1.hidden = YES;

}

-(IBAction)start{
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
}
-(IBAction)targetMethod:(id)sender{
       btn1.hidden = NO;
}
```

for use this code you drag and drop button on your xib and give the name is btn1 or as u wish...

i hope, this answer is helpful to you..

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:[Desc2 frame]];

[btn setTitle: [Desc2 text] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

This snippet code creates a `UIButton` where the Desc2 `UILabel` is and set the button's title with what Desc2 has.

You can place it inside of delayA method.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)delayA{

UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height); //add the parameters
[self.view addSubview:button];
}
```

hope it helps. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
NSTimer *aTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:(5.0) target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runner addTimer:aTimer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

and set the action which you want to perform in

```
-(void)timerFired:(NSTimer *) theTimer
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only try to show and hide buttons, use the alpha property.

```
// show button
[self.yourButton setAlpha: 1]

// hide button
[self.yourButton setAlpha: 0];
```